# OpenGL changing only r, g, b or a channel

Tags: opengl, colors, set, alpha, channel

Im trying to change only the alpha channel. Is there a way to do that ?
To apply colors, Im converting a hex value into 'r', 'g', 'b' and a floats. 'r', 'g' and 'b' are static but 'a' is varying for each object.

Comment: Pleasy clearify this question. It is totally unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: I`m searching something like : glColor1f for r, g, b or a. instead of glColor3f or glColor4f

Comment: there isn't such a thing. You will have to track the color manually, and re-supply the unchanged components.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the color your self. For example you have 4 floats holding one component each:

```
GLfloat r,g,b,a;
```

Whenever you want to change the alpha value, set a to desired value and call glColor4f

```
a = 0.5f;
glColor4f(r,g,b,a);
```

You can use this exact same solution to change other components individually too